# ArrayOutOfBoundsException in Image editing

Tags: java, image, processing

I'm trying to make a function that flip horizontally a given image.
Processing as you know use the `PImage` type.

Here what I'm trying:

```
PImage reverseHorOf(PImage toReverse){
  PImage toReturn = createImage(toReverse.width, toReverse.height, ARGB);
  toReturn.loadPixels();
  toReverse.loadPixels();
  for(int i = 0; i < toReverse.height; i ++)
    for(int j = 0; j < toReverse.width; j ++)
      toReturn.pixels[(i * width) + (width - 1 - j)] = toReverse.pixels[(i * width) + j];
  toReverse.updatePixels();
  toReturn.updatePixels();
  return toReturn;
}
```

@Java-only programmers:

- `createImage` is a "substitute" for `new PImage`;
- `loadPixels()` and `updatePixels()` are needed to [You don't say?!?] load and update the pixels of an image or the frame;
- I need to create a new `PImage` for two reasons: 1) Syntax meanings; 2) Semantic meaning: i can't copy a whole image if I start to modify part of it =P

So guys, what I tried is:

- Take the same line with `(i * width)`;
- Reach from the bottom, the start position of the line in `toReturn`;
- Reach the bottom from the start position of the line in `toReverse`;

What I have is an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException: 1499`.

I am making a mistake, but... where?

Comment: `toReverse.pixels[(i * width) + j]` You should check that `(i * width) + j` doesn't exceed the array dimension (Same in `(i * width) + (width - 1 - j)`).

Comment: what is the `width` variable?

Comment: Thank you All!
`width` is the frame width, I forgot to use `toReverse.width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas seem to be right in tote. But the only one thing which could lead to the mentioned exception here is unknown (for us) variable `width`. It seems, that this variable is not related to object `toReverse` and its dimension. I'm sure, you have to fix it like this:

```
toReturn.pixels[(i * toReverse.width) + (toReverse.width - 1 - j)] = toReverse.pixels[(i * toReverse.width) + j];
```